# Protocol subclass implementation

Tags: swift, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I have the following code in which I'm trying to force abstraction (abstract class/conformance):

PlayerProtocol:

```
protocol PlayerProtocol {
    func play();
    func stop();
    func pause();

    func getVolume() -> UInt32;
    func setVolume(level: UInt32);

    func isPaused() -> Bool;
    func isStopped() -> Bool;

    func onSessionResume();
    func onSessionInterupt();
}
```

BasicPlayer:

```
class BasicPlayer : PlayerProtocol {
    //some variables here..

    init() {
       //init some variables here..
    }

    func play() {
        fatalError("play() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func stop() {
        fatalError("stop() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func pause() {
        fatalError("stop() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func getVolume() -> UInt32 {
        fatalError("getVolume() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func setVolume(level: UInt32) {
        fatalError("setVolume() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func isPaused() -> Bool {
        fatalError("isPaused() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func isStopped() -> Bool {
        fatalError("isStopped() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func onSessionInterupt() {
        fatalError("onSessionInterupt() - pure virtual function called.");
    }

    func onSessionResume() {
        fatalError("onSessionResume() - pure virtual function called.");
    }
}
```

AudioPlayer:

```
class AudioPlayer : BasicPlayer, PlayerProtocol {
    private var device: COpaquePointer = nil;
    private var context: COpaquePointer = nil;
    private var source: ALuint = 0;
    private var buffer: ALuint = 0;
    private var interrupted: Bool = false;
    private var volume: Float = 50;


    override init() {
        super.init();
        //..
    }

    deinit {
        //..
    }

    override func play() {
        //..
    }

    override func stop() {
        //..
    }

    override func pause() {
        //..
    }

    override func setVolume(volume: UInt32) {
        //..
    }

    override func getVolume() -> UInt32 {
        //..
    }

    func isPlaying() -> Bool {
        //..
    }

    override func isPaused() -> Bool {
        //..
    }

    override func isStopped() -> Bool {
        //..
    }

    func isAudioPlaying() -> Bool {
        return AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().otherAudioPlaying;
    }

    override func onSessionInterupt() {
        self.pause();
    }

    override func onSessionResume() {
        self.play();
    }

    func setData(buffer: ALuint, source: ALuint) {
        self.buffer = buffer;
        self.source = source;
    }
}
```

But even though I specified that `AudioPlayer` implements the `PlayerProtocol`, it doesn't force me to implement all the member functions like `play`, `stop`, etc.. I can remove them and it doesn't complain. It's probably because the super class implements it but I can't figure out how to leave it un-implemented in the super class and allow the derived classes to do the implementation instead.

Basically, `BasicPlayer` is supposed to be abstract and any class inheriting it must implement "certain" members (not all). `OnSessionInterrupt` isn't implemented in the derived class. I need it to error.

How can I do this? How can I get it to error at compile time on un-implemented members in the derived classes but not the abstract class?

Answer (score 2):

`AudioPlayer` is a subclass of a class that already conforms to `PlayerProtocol`. Because you've implemented all of the methods in the superclass, those implementations are available in your subclass, so you aren't obliged to redeclare them.

It looks to me like you are conceptually abstracting your interface in two separate ways: through a protocol and through an abstract superclass. This might be superfluous? One or the other should be able to serve your purposes.